# Isomorphic Factor Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups

For $H$ and $K$ isomorphic normal subgroups of $G$, factor groups $G/H$ and $G/K$ need not be isomorphic.

But if G is free abelian then does the above still hold?

Comment: An extra comment on this fact, the first time I saw this I found it very strange, but when I got to understand quotienting out subgroups it became obvious why it isn't necessarily so. When making $G/H$, you aren't only using information about the group structure of $H$ and the group structure of $G$ seperately, but also about in what way $H$ lies in and interacts with $G$, this is in some sense not entirely dependent on what $H$ is isomorphic to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the case of $G=H=\mathbb{Z}$, and $K=2\mathbb{Z}\subset \mathbb{Z}$. Then $G\cong H\cong K$ but $G/H$ is the trivial group while $G/K=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.